# How to apply CSS code from array in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm creating a web game with different levels and need to change a div style using code stored inside an array in *AngularJS*. The game has two screens: the left one the user types the code in *HTML* and, the right one shows the result. This screen has a background and a div with the element created by the code. Each level has a different style for the background, so it needs to be loaded when the user changes the current level.

The *HTML* code is as follows:

```
<div id="background" ng-class="css"></div>
```

And the code in *AngularJS* is:

```
$scope.css = [
{
    //level one
    'background-image': 'url(url1)',
    'position' : 'absolute',
     ...
},
{
    //level two
    'background-image': 'url(url2)',
    ...
}];
```

Another approach is to use a variable called `$scope.cur_level` that I'm using get number of current level to use it in `ng-class` with conditions:

`ng-class="cur_level = '0' ? 'level_one' : 'level_two'"`

In this case, each level style was created in the *CSS* file. However, the style of the first level is loaded for every level. I really want use the array approach. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the correct way of using the ng-class directive:

```js
(function () {
 "use strict";
 const app = angular.module("app", []);

 app.controller("app.GameCtrl", $scope => {
      $scope.currentLevel = "1";
      $scope.setLevel = () => {
         $scope.currentLevel = $scope.currentLevel === '1' ? '2' : '1';
      };
  }
 );
 
})();
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 3em;
}


.level-one {
  background-color: red;
}

.level-two {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="app.GameCtrl">
  <div class="container" ng-class="{'level-one': currentLevel === '1', 'level-two': currentLevel === '2'}">
    {{currentLevel}}
  </div>
  <a href="" ng-click="setLevel();">Change Level</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried but it is not loading the style. My div code is `<div id="background" ng-class="{'level_one': cur_level === '0', 'level_two': cur_level === '1'}"></div>` and the screen is still white.

Comment: @MateusRocha, I've just improved my answer. I'd recommend you to check in the browser if the class is being applied to your element. Maybe another declaration is overriding its style.

Comment: I found the error: my ng-controller was called in edit screen tag (where I put my code). I moved it to body and now it's working. Also, I tried with the strict equal and didn't worked, but with '==' it did. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi again @Cristiano Soares. Now I'm trying to load a different style for the page based on level. There are too much levels in the game so I was thinking: is there some way to save the style in a array and load the style based on the level like: `ng-class="{'arrayStyle[currentLevel]' : level == 'currentLevel'}"`?

Comment: Hi @MateusRocha! In this case you don't even need to use the ng-class directive. You can handle the class level change directly in the class attribute of your element. I've made a pen to show you an example: https://codepen.io/criscoder/pen/exvjrg